# How could I alternate background-color between odd/even <dd> rows

Tags: html, css

I have a definition list as follows:

```
<dt>Term1</dt>
<dd>Definition1</dd>
<dt>Term2</dt>
<dd>Definition2</dd>
<dt>Term3</dt>
<dd>Definition3</dd>
<dt>Term4</dt>
<dd>Definition4</dd>
```

I would like to use CSS to give every odd row a different background-color using nth-child(odd) but this does not work with the structure of the definition list unless I can group each dt and dd together in a wrapper.

Does anybody know of a way I could achieve this alternating background effect?

Thanks

**EDIT**** I should have pointed out that I need the Term and the Definition to appear side by side. So each pair of DT & DD should have alternating colors.

Comment: The pseudo selector `dd:nth-child(odd)` should do it. To reverse the effect, use `(even)`

Comment: Which of the elements above should be in which background color? Your question is ambiguous - it's impossible to tell if you want Term1 in red, Definition1 in blue, Term2 in red again, etc; or if you want Term1 and Definition1 in red, Term2 and Definition2 in blue, etc.

Comment: @amn - I need the 1st DT and the 1st DD to be grey,
then I need the 3rd DT and 3rd DD to be grey

Comment: _"So each pair of DT & DD should have alternating colors."_ - then combine the odd/even solution with selecting the `dd` element immediately following a `dt`using the adjacent sibling combinator, `+`

Comment: tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for me:

```
dt, dd {
  background-color: blue;
}

dt:nth-child(4n+1), dt:nth-child(4n+1) + dd {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: This mostly works, but the background colour of the DT is limited by the size of the DT when compared to (say a longer) DD.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   dt:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#eee; }
   dd:nth-child(even){ background-color:#fff; }
```

Comment: This code change the color of all the dt and all the dd.